# Give Delta voucher to another person

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, delta-air-lines, vouchers

If I have a Delta voucher in my name, can I give it to another person to use, for example to my daughter?

Comment: What do the terms and conditions say, which should be attached to the vouchers?

Comment: You should be able to use the voucher to book the travel for any passenger name correct? Do you really need to actually transfer the voucher?

Comment: You mean I can use voucher for buying ticket for any person?

Comment: @DCTLib, I didn't see something about transfer in description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a paper voucher ....

Redemption/Transferability: Voucher is non-transferable unless assigned to someone traveling with the original voucher owner on the same reservation at the time the voucher is being redeemed.

In other words it can be applied to your daughter's airfare, as long as she is traveling on the same reservation as you are.

Answer (score -1):

> If I have Delta voucher on my name, can I give it to other person to use, for example to my daughter?

**No.** "All tickets are non-transferable per the fare rules. Name changes are not permitted."

Source: http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/support/faqs/general/customer-care-faqs.html

Comment: it isn't ticket, just compensation voucher for denied boarding.